# Would it be rude to mention "moved to Reddit" while closing a question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migration, reddit

I was about to add in my comment for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program-closed) question:

"Moved to Reddit"

but ... I don't want to start a comment war or anything ( even thought I have actually linked the closed question [there](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/bn676/cosmic_rays_what_is_the_probability_they_will/) ) .

Would it be rude to post such comment while closing a question.

**EDIT**

I think the title was misleading, I have change it to reflect what my real question is.

Comment: Why reddit and not somewhere else?

Comment: Why anywhere. If you think it doesn't belong just close it (if you've got the rep).

Comment: @ChrisF: I vote to close it. I was just about to add in my comment "This is interesting but doesn't belong to SO, try reddit" ( for instance ) But I wonder if that last part would be rude or not, which is the reason of this post.

Comment: this is arguably a SU question and has possibly been covered there as well http://superuser.com/questions/4048/should-i-use-ecc-ram-for-the-next-computer-i-build/22173#22173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it's a reddit-friendly (discussion) topic, then say so - that can be a valid reason to close.

Personally, I think the question belongs on Super User... but if you have a good argument for excluding it from all of SOFU, then reading it could help dissuade me from voting to migrate and therefore be useful.

Answer (score 1):

WTB RedditOverflow.com.

(I know about the damn StackExchange thing, so don't bother commenting about it...)

Comment: Chacha102, you can create RedditOverflow.com with stack exchange: http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree @kop, he should totally create a stack exchange site. Chacha, for more info, head to http://stackexchange.com

Comment: I suspect you mean that StackExchange thing as a joke, but it really exists, and you can use it to create your own site, such as RedditOverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

I've referred some subjective or argumentative topics to http://reddit.com/r/programming, as it's a good place to hold lengthy discussions. Another suitable place, especially for career advice, is [Ask Slashdot](http://ask.slashdot.org).  I wouldn't find your comment rude or out of place.